# How to find $(308!)^2 \pmod{617}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> How to find the $(308!)^2 \pmod{617}$?

I have no idea to calculate the modulus for large numbers.

Answer (score 7):

By Wilson's Theorem we have that if $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$ then:

$$\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$$

Now note that $617$ is such a prime number.

---

To understand why this is true, note that $p-k \equiv - k \pmod p$. Now do the substitution for $k = 1,2,3,\dots, \frac{p-1}{2}$ in the Wilson's Theorem and note that you have even number of such changes, so the minus signs will cancel out.

Comment: You want to square $(\frac{p-1}2)!$ surely?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oooops! I missed that part :)